# How do i mock an attribute within nested constructor using unittest

Tags: python-3.x, constructor, nested, python-unittest

This is what i am trying to test :

**src/DBOps.py**

```
class DBOps() :
    class dynamodbOps() :
        def __init__(self,db_table) :
            dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
            self.table = dynamodb.Table(db_table)
        def GetDBItem(self,pool):
            response = self.table.get_item(Key={'pool' : pool})
```

And this is the test case that is unsuccessful :

```
class test_GetDBItem(unittest.TestCase) :
    def setUp(self):
        self.db_ops = DBOps()
        db_table = "test_table"
        self.dyn = self.db_ops.dynamodbOps(db_table)

    @mock.patch('src.DBOps')
    def test_run_query_with_item(self, getItem_mock) :
        getItem_mock.dynamodbOps.table.get_item.return_value = {"Blah":"Blah Blah"}
        pool = 'some_pool'
        response = self.dyn.GetDBItem(pool)
```

I am trying to mock the 'table.get_item' call and failing at it no matter what i try. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out as below :

```
class test_GetDBItem(unittest.TestCase) :
  def setUp(self):
      db_ops = DBOps()
      db_table = "test_table"
      self.dyn = db_ops.dynamodbOps(db_table)

  def test_run_query_with_item(self) :
      with patch.object(self.dyn.table, 'get_item') as getItem_mock :
        getItem_mock.return_value = {"Blah":"Blah Blah"}
        pool = 'some pool'
        response = self.dyn.GetDBItem(quadra_pool)
```